# SUM a range of rows by looking up by a separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet. It has a timestamp in Column A and a dollar value in Column C.

I have another sheet that provides calculated values of the whole sheet, but I am also trying to provide a way for a user to type in a date as the start date cutoff. "Give me the number of entries since 10/1/2012" and "Give me the sum of all dollar values since 10/1/2012".

The count was easy, using a COUNTIF, however, I'm struggling to come up with the formula to give the dollar sum, based on the date cutoff. Since Date is in column A and dollars in column C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try SUMIF

`=SUMIF(A:A,">="&D2,C:C)`

where cutoff date is in D2